# Efficient two dimensional numpy array statistics

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have many 100x100 grids, is there an efficient way using numpy to calculate the median for every grid point and return just one 100x100 grid with the median values? Presently, I'm using a for loop to run through each grid point, calculating the median and then combining them into one grid at the end. I'm sure there's a better way to do this using numpy. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create as 100x100xN array (or stack together if that's not possible) and use `np.median` with the correct axis to do it in one go:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(100,100)
b = np.random.rand(100,100)
c = np.random.rand(100,100)
d = np.dstack((a,b,c))
result = np.median(d,axis=2)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr E! That makes perfect sense, I didn't know about the dstack function, but I like it!! Do you know if numpy similarly supports a function to get the 75th percentile? If not, that's alright, you've helped a lot already!!

Comment: Just do `np.sort(d,axis=2)` and grab the slice you want.

Answer (score 0):

How many grids are there?

One option would be to create a 3D array that is 100x100xnumGrids and compute the median across the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 0):

use axis parameter of median:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(100, 5, 5)

print np.median(data, axis=0)

print np.median(data[:, 0, 0])
print np.median(data[:, 1, 0])
```