# Can a python list hold a multi-dimentional array as its element?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to do image processing using python.

I try to create a list which holds numpy.ndarrays.

My code looks like this,

```
def Minimum_Close(Shade_Corrected_Image, Size):

    uint32_Shade_Corrected_Image = pymorph.to_int32(Shade_Corrected_Image)
    Angles = []

    [Row, Column] = Shade_Corrected_Image.shape


    Angles = [i*15 for i in range(12)] 



    Image_Close = [0 for x in range(len(Angles))]
    Image_Closing = numpy.zeros((Row, Column))

    for s in range(len(Angles)):

        Struct_Element = pymorph.seline(Size, Angles[s])
        Image_Closing = pymorph.close(uint32_Shade_Corrected_Image,Struct_Element )
        Image_Close[s] = Image_Closing

    Min_Close_Image = numpy.zeros(Shade_Corrected_Image.shape)

    temp_array = [][]
    Temp_Cell = numpy.zeros((Row, Column))

    for r in range (1, Row):
        for c in range(1,Column):
            for Cell in Image_Close:

                Temp_Cell = Image_Close[Cell]

                temp_array[Cell] = Temp_Cell[r][c]

            Min_Close_Image[r][c] = min(temp_array)    



    Min_Close_Image = Min_Close_Image - Shade_Corrected_Image    

    return Min_Close_Image
```

While running this code I'm getting error:

```
Temp_Cell = Image_Close[Cell]

TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

How can I make a data structure which holds different multi-dimensional arrays and then traverse through it??

Comment: You're not getting an `SyntaxError` from `temp_array = [][]`??

Comment: The problem you've found is in the innermost for loop, but I'm not sure how to tell you to fix it, because I don't understand what you're trying to do.  `for Cell in Image_close` makes `Cell` a reference to a 2d array (the first image in `Image_Close`).  Then you try to **index** `Image_Close` with that 2D array.  Clearly that isn't working, but I don't know what you're intending to do.

Comment: I have no idea how `temp_array = [][]` is working for you

Comment: Why aren't you putting your arrays into another array, rather than a list?

Comment: Maybe it's my lack of coffee but I'm finding the logic hard to follow. What's going on in that triple loop? You can find the min over a stack of images in a fast vectorized fashion without looping over pixels. Similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245466/efficient-two-dimensional-numpy-array-statistics/9245475#9245475) but with `np.min` instead of `median`

Comment: This code won't parse; so please post the actual code that is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a list of arrays is not necessary when you're using numpy.

I suggest rewriting the whole function like this:

```
def Minimum_Close(shade_corrected_image, size):

    uint32_shade_corrected_image = pymorph.to_int32(shade_corrected_image)

    angles = np.arange(12) * 15

    def pymorph_op(angle):
        struct_element = pymorph.seline(size, angle)
        return pymorph.close(uint32_shade_corrected_image, struct_element)

    image_close = np.dstack(pymorph_op(a) for a in angles)

    min_close_image = np.min(image_close, axis=-1) - shade_corrected_image

    return min_close_image
```

I lower cased variable names so that they stop getting highlighted as classes.

Comment: regarding the `array = np.dstack(f(i) for i in iter)`: I've been using this pattern a lot recently, but does anyone know of a better way of phrasing it with numpy?

Comment: it could equally be `np.dstack(i.f for i in iter)` where `i` is an object.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
for cnt,Cell in enumerate(Image_Close):
  Temp_Cell = Image_Close[cnt]
```